# Use Google Maps utils in .net Maui

Tags: visual-studio, google-maps, maui

How do you do this in .net Maui?

Step 1. Install the Maps SDK for Android utility library
Add the following dependency to your app's build.gradle file:

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.3.0'

}

Note:
I have Google Maps working. I want to use the advanced features of the utilities library.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup

Answer (score 0):

To use google maps utils with MAUI you need to create a project for library binding.

Here is a link on how to create such a project for Android in Xamarin:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

And how to migrate it for MAUI if needed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/android-binding-projects

You can find the aar file of google maps utils library here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils

Once the project is correctly configured and referenced to your main project, you should have access to ClusteredMarker, ClusterManager etc...